# Git Remove remote history

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-4

I am using laravel 4 framework and in order to stay up to date I have added a remote called upstream that points to the framework repo and ran `git fetch`. The problem is that it pulled the whole history of the framework in my local repo. 
Is there any way to delete that upstream history ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's the whole point of git - every repository clone is created equal. Do not worry much about having whole history - git is extremely efficient when storing whole history in git object store (provided that `git gc` is executed once in a while, which it is).

It is relatively rare situation when size of compressed git object store (kept under `.git` directory) exceeds size of checkout of the top of the tree.

In other words, you are not going to save much by removing remote history (hardly few percent). If it bothers you in terms of seeing many remote branches (but it really shouldn't!), you can simply remove this remote:

```
git remote rm upstream
```

and you will not see it or its branches anymore.

I highly doubt that you will see big space savings by using shallow clone (`--depth=1`), but you will see big downside it - shallow clone cannot be committed into. So, if you want to make your own commits, do not use shallow clones.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, in my case git remote rm upstream stuill leaves me with the history, I found a walk around though will add it as answers

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the whole history, then use set `--depth` option of `git fetch` and `git clone`. Additionally, if you are interested in only one branch, then you can use the `--single-branch` option when cloning:

```
git clone --single-branch --branch=master --depth=1 git://......
```

Comment: Ok thanks, that's good to know, but how can i get rid of that history now ?